# C expression that sets the last n bits of int variable to zero

Tags: c, unix

In other words, sets the last 5 bits of integer variable x to zero, also it must be in a portable form.

I was trying to do it with the << operator but that only moves the bits to the left, rather than changing the last 5 bits to zero.

11001011 should be changed to 11000000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 32-bit integers, you should be able to mask off those bits using the & (bitwise and) operator.

```
x & 0xFFFFFFE0.
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND

Answer (score 5):

Create a mask that blanks out that last `n` integers if it is bitwise-ANDed with your int:

```
x &= ~ ((1 << n) - 1);
```

The expression `1 << n` shifts 1 by `n` places and is effectively two to the power of `n`. So for 5, you get 32 or `0x00000020`. Subtract one and you get a number that as the `n`  lowest bits set, in your case `0x0000001F`. Negate the bits with `~` and you get `0xFFFFFFE0`, the mask others have posted, too. A bitwise AND with your integer will keep only the bits that the mask and your number have in common, which can only bet bits from the sixth bit on.

Comment: This fails when n = sizeof(int)

Comment: @WingerSendon: You mean when `n == CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int)`? Yes, but masking away a number of bits that is equal to or greater than the bit width of the value is setting it to zero. That special case is easily caught if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bitwise and `&` for this

```
int x = 0x00cb;
x = x & 0xffe0;
```

This keeps the higher bits and sets the lower bits to zero.